# How to show an Oracle Apex 5 Error Message on Button Condition?

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I want a condition on a button, it searches through an email field and looks for '@gmail.com' and if it fails to find it, the button's dynamic actions won't be triggered and an error message shows saying 'Must be gmail account'

Any help would be really appreciated.

I've had another idea of putting the code in the buttons dynamic actions where it has an IF statement, which works in the sense that if it isn't found then the button's dynamic actions won't work.

However, I need help showing an error message. I've researched it online and I don't understand.

Comment: So the button is always there and can always be pressed, but if the email field does not contain "@email" you want an error displayed?  And what does the button do exactly if all is OK - submit the page?

Comment: What do you call "showing an error message"? Javascript function `alert()`, for example?

Comment: Yeah. So when the field has '@gmail.com' in it, the button will continue on to input the email into a table along with the user details. It is part of a registration page.

Comment: Showing an error message as in validation notification e.g. password must be 16 characters long or email must be gmail

Answer (score 1):

You need to make following:

1. In button's properties choose: `Action` - `Defined by Dynamic Action`
2. Create new Dynamic Action with following properties:

   - `Event` - `Click`
   - `Selection Type` - `Button`
   - `Button` - choose desired button
   - `Condition` - `JavaScript Expression`
   - `Value` - write this code:

     `$x("P1_MY_EMAIL_ITEM").value.substring(
          $x("P1_MY_EMAIL_ITEM").value.indexOf("@")) == "@gmail.com"`
   - `Action` - `Submit Page`
   - `False Action` - `Alert` with `Text` - `It is not a GMail account!`
   - All checkboxes `Fire on Page Load` have to be unchecked!
3. Run the page

How it works: Dynamic action could be fired on condition. For every Dynamic Action with a condition, you can create several true actions and false actions, which are fired if the condition is true or false respectively. So you just need to create a condition, which checks user's input (compare end of a line with `@gmail.com`), your true action will be `Submit` and false action - alert.